# Is there any method in which you can pass a mathematical statement and it will give you a result?

Tags: c#, math

Is there any method in C# in which you will pass a mathematical statement, and that method will give you the result for example you will pass this string

`1+2-3/4*5`

and it will give you in return

`0`

Comment: I think you mean, it will give you in return [-0.75](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1+%2B+2+-+3%2F4*5) ;-)

Comment: You don't need third party libraries at all. try this `            var res = new DataTable().Compute("1+2-3/4*5", null);`

Comment: I am immediately suspicious of a solution that requires spinning up a DataTable to do something that is essentially unrelated to Data operations. You will find the NCalc library very robust and better optimized for this kind of thing.

Comment: Do you really want it to return 0? In other words, you want it to specifically ignore correct order of operations and just perform operations in the order in which they appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NCalc](http://ncalc.codeplex.com/)

```
Expression e = new Expression("2 + 3 * 5");   
Debug.Assert(17 == e.Evaluate());
```